# Oracle path has been changed,Toad unable to locate oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I have installed oracle on external hard disk,the drive name of external hard disk has been changed.now i am opening toad but it is unable to locate oracle.kindly give the solution ASAP

Comment: Try using the printenv command and see if there is a variable pointing to the old installation. If there is update it however your OS handles setting variables,

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct and you're running Windows, you can use the SUBST ccommand-line command to create a drive letter alias.  For example, if your external hard disk was originally drive F: when you installed Oracle, but now it's showing up as E:, then the command

```
SUBST F: E:\
```

in a command window will cause the F: drive letter to be assigned to the path E:\, and that might just get things working.  Note that for this to work nothing else can be using the F: drive letter.

Share and enjoy.